# problem using tex4ht with xr-hyper when other documents are in separate folders

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht, xr-hyper

ps. a zip file at bottom which contains all files.

I am splitting my large document into smaller separate documents, where now each chapter will be compiled separately (in its own folder), as separate PDF file (not using `\include` or `\input`, but as a separate document with its own `title` and `\begin{document}`)

But I still need to have references from the main document to the other documents to build tables and references to problems in each chapter.

So I am using `xr-hyper`. Which worked well. I have this MWE tree to show my current setup

```
   main.tex
      |
      +------ chapter_1/ch1.tex
      +------ chapter_2/ch2.tex
```

I put each chapter in separate folder to reduce clutter. This is what my main.tex, ch1.tex and ch2.tex  look like

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument{chapter_1/ch1} %notice folder name included
\externaldocument{chapter_2/ch2}
\begin{document}
See problem \hyperref[1]{1} below and problem \hyperref[2]{2}.
\end{document}
```

and ch1.tex which is inside folder chapter_1/

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1 in document ch1.tex}
\section{some section name}
\subsection{problem 1 from some book}
\label{1}
This is problem 1
\end{document}
```

and ch2.tex

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}        
\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter 2 in document ch2.tex}
\section{some section name}
\subsection{problem 2 from some book}
\label{2}
This is problem 2
\end{document}
```

Next, compiled ch1.tex,ch2.tex and finally main.tex (each in its own folder) and in the order above, all using `lualatex`.

Now I opened main.pdf and the links there are correct and work in the pdf.

Next, I did the same for tex4ht. Compiled ch1.tex,ch2.tex then main.tex in this order, all using the commands

```
   cd chapter_1
   make4ht ch1.tex 'mathjax,htm'
   cd ../chapter_2
   make4ht ch2.tex 'mathjax,htm'
   cd ..
   make4ht main.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

Then opened `main.htm` and it shows correct output

[image]

Now here is the problem, when I click on the link, it drops the folder name from the link. The link for `1` says

```
ch1.htm#x1-30001.1.1
```

instead of

```
chapter_1/ch1.htm#x1-30001.1.1
```

By manually editing the link and adding the folder name `chapter_1/` to it, then it works and opens chapter 1 page correctly.

I can fix all of this by having all separate documents (main.tex, ch1.tex and ch2.tex) in same top level folder.

But to reduce clutter, and since I have many chapters that I want to make now completely separate PDF files for each chapter (but still have cross references from main document to them), it will be much better to have each in separate folder to make it easier to manage and reduce clutter in same folder, since I need to compile each one separately now.

This looks like a bug in tex4ht, in that it drops the folder name from the reference. Or Am I doing something wrong?

This is [trying_separate_chapters.zip](https://12000.org/tmp/04232022/trying_separate_chapters.zip)  which contains all files and folders.

[image]

TL 2021

### Update 4/30/2022

I've been testing this in tex4ht. I found a big problem. Everything works fine as long as the separate chapter is compiled all as one large HTML file with no splitting. Then the links from the other document (main) show up correctly.

Once I split the chapter, and recompile everything in correct order, then the parent losses the link and they no long show up.  Since I split all the chapters (because they are large) then this will not work as is for me.

I hope there is an easy solution for this. Below I give MWE showing this and also a zip file with everything in it to make it easier to see.

I have this layout

```
   main.tex
      |
    CHAPTERS/
      |
   chapters_1/
      |
    ch1.tex
```

Here is main.tex

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument{CHAPTERS/chapter_1/ch1}    
\begin{document}    
See problem \hyperref[1]{1}     
\end{document}
```

And this is ch1.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{some section name}
\subsection{problem 1 from some book}
\label{1}
THis is problem 1
\end{document}
```

Now I do the following

```
   cd CHAPTERS/chapter_1/
   make4ht  -ulm default  -a debug ch1.tex 'mathjax,htm,4'
   cd ../..
   make4ht  -ulm default  -a debug main.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

Then look at main.htm to see if the link worked, it did not. It just shows the number `1` but it is not clickable. Here is the raw HTML of main.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='main.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", }, }; </script> 
 <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 8 --><p class='noindent'>See problem <a>1</a>
</p>   
 
</body> 
</html>
```

Now I do the following

```
   cd CHAPTERS/chapter_1/
   make4ht  -ulm default  -a debug ch1.tex 'mathjax,htm'
   cd ../..
   make4ht  -ulm default  -a debug main.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

Notice, I removed the split above on the chapter.

Now I look at main.htm and link is active and working. Here is the new raw HTML of main.htm. You see, now it worked

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='main.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", }, }; </script> 
 <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 8 --><p class='noindent'>See problem <a href='CHAPTERS/chapter_1/ch1.htm#x1-20001.1'>1</a>
</p>   
 
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is a [zip](https://12000.org/tmp/04302022_sep_chapters/trying_separate_chapters_bug.zip) file the contains the above layout and all the files.

Comment: your description seems wrong, you say you did `make4ht ch1.tex 'mathjax,htm' ; make4ht ch2.tex 'mathjax,htm'` but don't you change directory in between? local links in tex are relative to the working direcory of the process, not relative to the document, so it's impossible to understand your issue without knowing the current direcory when you run thse commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add the subdirectory support with these `.4ht` files.

First, we need to save directory for the external file in a macro for a later retrieval. We can do that in `xrhyper-hooks.4ht`:

```
% xrhyper-hooks.4ht (2020-10-17-13:53), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2020 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2020-10-17-13:53}

\:AtEndOfPackage{\let\XR:\XR@
    \def\XR@[#1][#2]#3{%
      % save directory for the linked file
      \filename@parse{#3}
      % \filename@base is filename, \filename@area directory
      \expandafter\xdef\csname xr:dir:\filename@base\endcsname{\filename@area}
      \AtBeginDocument{\XR:[#1][#2]{#3}}
    }%
}
```

The important code is this:

```
      % save directory for the linked file
      \filename@parse{#3}
      % \filename@base is filename, \filename@area directory
      \expandafter\xdef\csname xr:dir:\filename@base\endcsname{\filename@area}
```

It uses LaTeX's command `\filename@parse` to extract path, basename, and extension for the external file. These parts are stored in `\filename@area` and `\finelame@base` commands. We then make csname that links filename to the directory.

It can be then used in `xr-hyper.4ht`:

```
% xr-hyper.4ht (2016-12-21-15:03), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2003-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2016 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2016-12-21-15:03}

   \let\XR:loop=\XR@loop
\def\XR@loop#1{%
   \def\:temp##1.aux{\openin15=##1.xref
\ifeof15
   \:warning{missing ##1.xref for ##1.aux}%
   \let\:temp\empty
\else
   \def\:temp{\input ##1.xref}%
\fi
\closein15  \:temp
}%
   \catcode`\:=11
     \expandafter\ifx \csname xr:CrossWord\endcsname\relax
  \let\xr:CrossWord=\Cross:Word
  \def\Cross:Word##1##2{%
     \expandafter\let\csname  cw:\cw:format{##1##2}\endcsname\:UnDef
     \xr:CrossWord{##1}{##2}}%
\fi
%
     \:temp#1%
   \catcode`\:=12
   \XR:loop{#1}%
}
\long\def\XR@test#1#2#3#4\XR@{%
  \ifx#1\newlabel
     \expandafter\xdef\csname r@\XR@prefix#2\endcsname{\XR:rEfLiNK #3}%
%
  \else\ifx#1\@input
     \edef\XR@list{\XR@list#2\relax}%
  \fi\fi
  \ifeof\@inputcheck\expandafter\XR@aux
  \else\expandafter\XR@read\fi}

   \def\XRrEfLiNK[#1]#2#3{%
      \filename@parse{#1}% Get basename of the linked html file, 
      % xr:dir\filename@base contains file's directory
      \a:xr[\csname xr:dir:\filename@base\endcsname#1]{#2}{}%
   \ifx\hyperrefLabel\:UnDef #3\else \hyperrefLabel\fi \b:xr}
\NewConfigure{xr}{2}
\Configure{xr}{\Link}{\EndLink}
\def\XR:rEfLiNK#1#2#3#4#5{{\xr:rEfLiNK#1}{\xr:rEfLiNK#2}{\xr:rEfLiNK#3}}
\def\xr:rEfLiNK#1#2{\noexpand\XRrEfLiNK[\Get:HFile#2-]{#2}}
\def\Get:HFile#1-#2-{\:LikeRef{)F\:gobble #1F-}}

\Hinput{xr}
\endinput
```

The important code is this:

```
   \def\XRrEfLiNK[#1]#2#3{%
      \filename@parse{#1}% Get basename of the linked html file, 
      % xr:dir\filename@base contains file's directory
      \a:xr[\csname xr:dir:\filename@base\endcsname#1]{#2}{}%
   \ifx\hyperrefLabel\:UnDef #3\else \hyperrefLabel\fi \b:xr}
```

The `\csname xr:dir:\filename@base\endcsname#1` should expand to full name of the linked HTML file, including directory.

This is the resulting HTML code:

```html
<!-- l. 10 --><p class='noindent'>See problem <a href='chapter_1/ch1.htm#x1-30001.1.1'>1</a> below and problem <a href='chapter_2/ch2.htm#x1-30001.1.1'>2</a>.
</p>
```

Comment: hello Michal. Will there two .4ht be part of TL 2022 if I update it, or do I need to keep copy of them in my source tree? Just wanted to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: OK, please ignore the above question. I just did full update of TL 2022 and your fix was there. So I do not need to copy these .4ht you show.   I was starting to test this setup that is why I asked. Thanks again for the fix. This will be very useful.

Comment: @Nasser I always put fixes bug fixes for packages to TeX4ht sources as soon as possible, so they are usually added to TeX Live in few days :)

Comment: Hello Michal. I found a BIG problem with this. it only works when compiling the chapters without any splitting. Once I split a chapter, and recompile everything, then links are lost. tex4ht losses track of it and does not produce a link to click on. I will make a bug report on this. Without the ability to split the chapter, this will not work. I Will update my question soon to give the new example showing this problem. I already have a MWE to show this with a zip file.